# How to "close"/"disable" root folder temporarily without removing it from workspace in VS Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, directory, project, working-directory

Do you guys know the way to disable certain folders temporarily (to exclude them from searches, only see the git repo linked to open folder, only run Java build task with open folder etc.), but without removing it from workspace and still show up on the list of folders, so it can easily be re-enabled.

If you have the similar situation and no good solution, please upvote the feature request at:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182803

Only way for now is to remove the folder from VScode completely.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily edit the workspace settings' `search.exclude` setting to exclude paths from search functionality. It's not an ideal solution especially if you track the workspace settings in version control, but it's a workaround. If you want to "ignore" things at a deeper level, use the `files.exclude` setting.

Unfortunately, `files.exclude` does not seem to affect the SCM View. You can right click repositories there and select "close repository" and then later reopen then using the `Git: Open Repository` or `Git: Reopen Closed Repositories` commands in the command palette.

If you're using the Search View, you can expand the search details and edit the "files to include" and "files to exclude" fields, which take comma-separated lists of glob patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Other feature like Git Source Control, Java build task require to be excluded as well.

Comment: @Jocular see edit. also, I just fixed a mistake.